# Using AngularJS Resolve in order to fetch API data before DOM is rendered

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am continuing to have issues where my templates and directives are throwing errors because they are trying to be `$compile`d before the data is actually set. This is because it takes time for the API response to get back.

Therefore, I am trying to convert my API call to work in the `resolve` property of my route, however I cannot figure out how to do it correctly. Here is what I have:

**My State Provider w/ resolve property**

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
                url: '/',
                controller: 'LandingController',
                resolve: {
                    data: ['API', function(API){
                        return API.Backups.getAll(function (data) {


                            return data.result;


                        });
                    }]
                }
            })
```

**My controller**

```
app.controller('LandingController', ['$scope', 'API', function ($scope, API, data) {

        $scope.data = data;
......
```

I am using an Angular service that provides a `$resource` in order to get the API data, however something is not working still because my `data` parameter in the controller is still undefined.

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I needed. I just needed to return the `$resource.$promise` instead of just the `$resource`. After doing that, everything worked great!

**Solution**

```
$stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
                url: '/',
                controller: 'LandingController',
                resolve: {
                    res: ['API', function(API){
                        return API.Backups.getAll(function (data) {
                            return data.result;
                        }).$promise;
                    }]
                }
            })
```

Comment: Yes. Its not clear from your example what the API call is returning i.e. it could take just a callback and return nothing which doesn't help do any resolves.

Comment: API is a service, Backups is a resource, and getALL is an action on that resource

Comment: Yes, I missed that you mentioned `$resource`, but as you figured out `getAll()` does not return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code for `API.Backups.getAll()` I can't tell, but the `resolve` function needs to return a "promise" which can be provided by the Angular `$q`:

```
resolve: ['$q', 'API', function($q, API) {

    // 1. $q provides the deferred which satisfies the "promise" API
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // 2. call your API
    API.Backups.getAll(function (data) {
        // 4. resolve the promise with data that was returned
        deferred.resolve(data.result);
    });

    // 3. return the promise
    return deferred.promise;
}]
```

The numbered comments show the order things will occur. Angular will not instantiate your controller until `resolve()` is called on the promise (`deferred`).

see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Thanks a lot.. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961640/using-angular-promises-and-defers-effectively which explains the downfall to this solution. At least, I think even your solution would cause this

Comment: Yes, this solution is basically the same as yours below but it answers the question asked.