# Using Angular Promises and Defers effectively

Tags: angularjs

In Angular (and all SPA JS Frameworks), it is assumed that page navigation be extremely quick and "seamless" to the user.  The only bottleneck to this speed is the use of API calls to retrieve data from our server.  Therefore, it seems reasonable to find a solution where we can render an entire page, except for the physical data being presented, while we wait for our API call to get a response.

I am fairly new to Angular and I am running into a few problems that are keeping me from achieving the above goal and functionality. Let me take you through the 2 problems I came across while learning Angular

**Problem 1: API response is too slow for Angular**

At first, I was simply calling my API from within the controller.  I have multiple tables of data that are going to be populated after I receive my response.  Before the response is gotten, my tables have a simple `<tr>` that contains a .gif "spinner" that represents the loading of data.  I have a `$scope.gotAPIResponse` property that is set to `false` initially and then after the API responds, it gets set to `true`.

I use this boolean in order to show and hide the "spinner" and the table data respectably.  This causes the HTML to render successfully and everything looks fine to the user. However, a closer look at the JavaScript console and you can see that Angular threw many errors because it was attempting to `$compile` my templates BEFORE the API call got a response.  Errors are never a good thing, so I had to improvise.

*Inside the 'LandingController'*

```
function init() {

            $scope.gotAPIResponse = false;

            // Get Backup data
            API.Backups.getAll(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.ActiveCurrentPage = 0;
                $scope.InactiveCurrentPage = 0;
                $scope.pageSize = 25;
                $scope.data = data.result;
                $scope.gotAPIResponse = true;

            });
        }
```

*Here is the HTML template that throws errors.. both native template and pagination directive throws errors*

```
<tbody>
     <tr ng-hide="gotAPIResponse"><td colspan="6"><p class="spinner"></p></td></tr>
     <tr ng-if="gotAPIResponse" ng-repeat="active in data.ActiveBackups | paginate:ActiveCurrentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
               <td><a ui-sref="order.overview({ orderId: active.ServiceId })" ng-click="select(active)">{{ active.Customer }}</a></td>
               <td>{{ active.LastArchived }}</td>
               <td>{{ active.ArchiveSizeGB | number:2 }}</td>
               <td>{{ active.NumMailboxes }}</td>
               <td>{{ active.ArchivedItems }}</td>
               <td><input type="button" class="backup-restore-btn" value="Restore" /></td>
      </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div pagination backup-type="active"></div>
```

**Problem 2: Using resolve property is blocking everything**

I then looked towards the `resolve` property that is available in the `$stateProvider` (ui-router) and `$routeProvider` (basic Angular).  This allowed me to defer the instantiation of the Controller until the `$promise` on my API call was received.

This worked how it should have and I no longer received any errors because the API response was available before the HTML template could be rendered.  The problem with this however, was that when you attempted to go to that state or route, the entire view would be unavailable for a split second until the `$promise` was received.  This would appear to "lag" or "block" to the user (which just looks terrible)

*Using resolve property*

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
                url: '/',
                controller: 'LandingController',
                resolve: {
                    res: ['API', function(API){
                        return API.Backups.getAll(function (data) {
                            return data.result;
                        }).$promise;
                    }]
                }
            })
```

*Then this controller is instantiated after API call, but the time between this is like 1-2 seconds...way too slow!*

```
app.controller('LandingController', ['$scope', 'API', 'res',  function ($scope, API, res) {

        $scope.data = res.result;
...
```

**Solution: Right in between**

In order to solve this, we need a solution that is right in between the 2 that I have already tried.  We need to instantiate the controller as quick as possible so `$scope.gotAPIResponse` can be set and therefore cause the "spinner" and rest of the DOM to show, however, we need to defer just specific parts of the HTML template and other Directives so that Errors are not thrown.

Is there an effective solution to this problem that people are using in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

In the end, this ended up being a much simpler fix. After some discussion we refactored the view a bit in order to avoid the `ng-repeat` executing before the `ng-if` which wasn't the desired behavior.

So instead of this:

```
<tbody>
     <tr ng-if="!gotAPIResponse">
       <!-- show spinner -->
     </tr>
     <tr ng-if="gotAPIResponse" ng-repeat="stuf in stuffs">
       <!-- lots o' DOM -->
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

We pulled the `ng-if` up one level to this:

```
<tbody ng-if="!gotAPIResponse">
     <tr >
       <!-- show spinner -->
     </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-if="gotAPIResponse">
     <tr ng-repeat="stuf in stuffs">
       <!-- lots o' DOM -->
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

This way the `ng-if` isn't being duplicated for each row, and will halt further processing until the condition is satisfied.

---

### Original Answer:

This is actually simple to achieve by using a directive and listening to some route change events on the `$rootScope`

The idea is to toggle a property on scope that can be used to Show/Hide some element. In this case a simple "Loading..." text, but in your case it could easily be used to show a spinner.

```
var routeChangeSpinner = function($rootScope){
 return {
   restrict:'E',
   template:"<h1 ng-if='isLoading'>Loading...</h1>",
   link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
     scope.isLoading = false;

     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
       scope.isLoading = true;
     });
     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
       scope.isLoading = false;
     });
   }
 };
};
routeChangeSpinner.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

app.directive('routeChangeSpinner', routeChangeSpinner);
```

Then inside your HTML you would simply do this:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- I will show up while a route is changing -->
  <route-change-spinner></route-change-spinner>

  <!-- I will be hidden as long as a route is loading -->
  <div ng-if="!isLoading" class="col-lg-12" ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

Voila! Simple way to show a loading indicator while changing routes.

### [Full Punker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wbjpm7l3e0mHpeOUzrkZ?p=preview)

Comment: I am trying to show the spinner until an API call is finished, not just until the $routeChangeSuccess event fires.

Comment: @MattHintzke - Yes, but if you use this on your `resolve` as I am simulating in the Plunker it will achieve the desired result.

Comment: hmmm that is interesting. So the resolve occurs before a Controller is instantiated, but not before Directives?

Comment: @MattHintzke - Angular will wait until the resolve is satisfied until it finalizes your route. So it happens before the view and controller are instantiated and injected into your `ng-view`

Comment: Ok, so I wired up my project to be like yours and I am still getting the "blocking" effect like I was before instead of seeing the page render. I changed the timeout to be 5 seconds in order to clearly see the result. I don't understand how you are able to get "Loading..." to render before the resolve occurs?

Comment: @MattHintzke - This is going to be difficult to track down without seeing your code, but make sure that the directive is included **outside** of your `ng-view`.

Comment: Oh, so maybe it is the way my views and DOM is structured.. I have my root url '/' as the one that uses the resolve and the controller for that view is what populates my `<table>`s. I think the problem is I need a new way to include the `<table>`s that are being populated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58020/discussion-between-josh-and-matt-hintzke).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do (example below):

1. Encapsulate your HTML in a directive
2. Create data in your controller (which you receive from the server side) and initialize it to an empty or initial value
3. Pass this data to your directive to have an isolated scope
4. Now fetch the data in your controller explicitly using the $http service and on resolution of the promise set the data tied to the directive to the data retrieved from the server
5. The directive will automatically update when the $http service code runs in the controller

Here's an explanation of the example I provided:

1. The controller initializes data to [1,2] but then calls the function changedata() which calls $http service to get the weather in New York and adds that to the data array. Hence you see "Sky is Clear" (or something else depending on when you run this example) rendered in your directive.

Here's the [plnkr showing directive update with $http](http://plnkr.co/edit/dMjKggQjRGzRqXtunesC?p=preview)

```
// index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="button" ng-click="changedata()" value="Change"/>
    <div myview data="model.data"></div>
  </body>

</html>


// app.js

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.model = {
    data: ["1", "2"]
  };

  $scope.changedata = function() {
    // updating data explicitly
    $scope.model.data = [4, 5, 6];

    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    return $http.get(url, {
      params: {
        q: "New York, NY"
      }
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log("result=");
      console.log(result);
      if (result !== null) {
        $scope.model.data.push(result.data.weather[0].description);
        return result.data.weather[0].description;
      }
      return "Weather not found";
    });
  };

  // updating data implicitly
  $scope.changedata();
});

app.directive("myview", function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<table><tr ng-repeat="d in data"><td>{{d}}</td></tr></table>',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: I will try this out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem of getting errors when the template renders is because `data` does not exist until after the promise resolves. A simple `$scope.data = { ActiveBackups:null }` before initiating your API call should solve that. When angular evaluates the `ng-repeat` expression `active in data.ActiveBackups` it will no longer be trying to reference the undefined attribute `data`.

If you have a longer loading request then you can have more control over the UX by not using resolves. Otherwise resolves tend to make for simpler controller code.